# Socket programming in C/C++ - gcc char * warning

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deprecated conversion from string constant to char * error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415326/deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-error)

I'm writting a program in C/C++ which is attempting to communicate over a UDP socket.

The code I'm working on has a variable, `char *servIP`, which is set through an input parameter to the main function. However, I want the input parameter to be optional, so I have the code:

```
if(argc > 1)
    servIP = argv[1];           /* First arg: server IP address (dotted quad) */
else
    servIP = "127.0.0.1";
```

`servIP` later gets converted into a more network-usable form.

When I compile this, I get a warning saying **"warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to char*"**.

I assume this isn't the correct way to enter that IP address; what is a better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126512/deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char has your answer

Comment: Just a note that you could eventually check if the content of `argv[1]` is a valid IP address.

Comment: do you realise, that your question has nothing to do with "Socket programming", "UDP".. ?

Comment: Are you programming in C or in C++? They're two different languages.

Comment: problem solution, found thanks to @Karoly Horvath, is just to do: char ip[] = "127.0.0.1"; servIP = ip;

Answer (score 4):

declare `servIP` as a `const char *` instead of `char *` or, if that's not possible, `strdup("127.0.0.1")` (in the second case, just remember to `free` it later)

the effect of modifying a string literal is undefined, which is why c++ assigns the type "array of n const char" to a string literal. the compiler is warning you about the conversion from a const data type to a non-const one.

you can use `std::string` instead, and then when you need a C-style pointer to the underlying characters, you can use [std::string::c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).