# Caesar Cipher Function using unsigned char?

Tags: c

I am working on a Caesar function, which given the input and the offset, returns the output. I'm not sure if I am doing it. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated. 
Also if someone could explain me how to work with unsigned chars.

```
void encrypt(unsigned char* message_input, char off, unsigned char* message_output) {

    int m_inp;

    while(*(message_input+ m_inp)!=EOF)
    {
        *(message_output+ m_inp) = (*((unsigned char*)input + m_inp) + offset )%256;
    }

}
```

Comment: `EOF` is of type `int` and has a negative value. All values of objects of type `unsigned char` are positive. Your comparison will always be *true* (for ever and ever and ever ...).

Comment: without initializing m_inp , you can't dereference (message_output + m_inp)

Comment: just means , i am trying to achieve this using unsigned char, not signed chars or just chars.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of correctness and stylistic issues with the code.

### Correctness issues

1. The loop variable, `m_inp`, is not initialized.
2. It is unlikely that an `unsigned char` can ever equal `EOF`.  The value of `EOF` is -1.  The loop will never finish (unless you are on a *very* strange architecture).
3. The traditional Caesar cipher operates alphabetically, rather than on the whole ASCII character set.

### Stylistic issues

Using more "stylistically correct" C will make it easier for other programmers to read your code.  These are *subjective.*

1. The name `m_inp` is a poor name for a loop variable in a short loop.  Use `i` instead.
2. It is easier to read `ptr[i]` instead of `*(ptr + i)`, even though they are exactly equivalent in C.
3. Marking the input as `const unsigned char *` makes it more obvious that it is not modified.
4. Use `int` instead of `char` for the offset.
5. Traditionally, function outputs go on the left, inputs go on the right.  This is not important, however.

### Revised code

Here is a sample revision.  It takes a NUL-terminated string, and writes the Caesar encoded / decoded version to an output buffer.  This is how I would write the function, not necessarily how you would write it:

```
void caesar(char *output, const char *input, int shift)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
        if (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z')
            output[i] = (input[i] - 'a' + shift) % 26 + 'a';
        else if (input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'Z')
            output[i] = (input[i] - 'A' + shift) % 26 + 'A';
        else
            output[i] = input[i];
    }
    output[i] = '\0';
}
```

Note that Caesar encryption and decryption are actually the same operation, just with different shift values.  So if you encrypt with a shift of 3, you can decrypt with a shift of -3 (or equivalently, 23).

Also note that you can replace `unsigned char` with `char` or vice versa and everything will work exactly the same (although you'd need to cast the inputs).

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written has a lot of mistakes

1) You have not initialized m_inp , but you are deferencing (message_output + m_inp)

2) You are checking the input string for EOF , which makes no sense.

Please have a look at this code , it is a much better implementation of caesar cipher

```
#include <stdio.h>

void caesar (char cipher[], int shift);

int main () {

char cipher[50];
int shift;

printf("Enter text to be encrypted IN CAPITAL LETTERS ONLY: ");
scanf("%s", cipher);

printf("How many shifts do you prefer? 1-10 only: ");
scanf("%d", &shift);

caesar (cipher, shift);

return 0;
}

void caesar (char cipher[], int shift) {
  int i = 0;

  while (cipher[i] != '\0') {
    if ((cipher[i] += shift) >= 65 && (cipher[i] + shift) <= 90) {
      cipher[i] += (shift);
     } else {
      cipher[i] += (shift - 25); 
       }
    i++;
   }
  printf("%s", cipher);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a string literal.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I mean the non mutable char * message_input and char * message_output strings

Comment: @ i made the changes above. Does that look rite?

Comment: What makes them immutable?

Comment: @DietrichEpp , I thought  i learnt that the string created is constant , and modifying them is undefined , but cannot recall where , please help me out if you can . But i have found out that it is depreciated in c++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126512/deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char

Comment: @DietrichEpp I have read the part where you cant change char * "str" , in page 73 of a book called "head first C" . The book goes on to say that "str" , gets stored in constant [read only] section of data memory. If there is any mistake in my understanding please do correct me.

Comment: @BarathBushan: A string literal like `"str"` should not be modified, you are correct about that.  However, if you look at the code in the question, there are no string literals anywhere.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Sorry for wasting your time , i made a wrong assumption , that the user would pass the string itself as i/p parameter while calling the encrypt function.

Comment: It's not a waste of time, that's what the site is here for.