# deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ in code

Tags: c++, string, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524356/c-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char)

I am getting "deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’" error on gcc compiler at 3 places.

When I was compiling it on codeblock, no error was there.

```
char* decodeCode(char* encodedString)
{
    const char*  decodedString = "";   // ERROR
    char* a = encodedString;
    char store[10000];

    for(int j=0;j <strlen(a);j++)
    {
        if (isdigit(a[j]) || a[j] == '#')
            continue;
        else return "";    //ERROR
    }   
} 

int main()
{
    const char* a;
    a = decodeCode("6999066263304447777077766622337778");   // ERROR
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Have you any idea how I could fix it? If so, please write it down clearly (I am newbie...).

Comment: A string literal is of type `const char[]`, which means you cannot modify its contents. Casting to `char *` makes a pointer with no such constraints. Try `const char *`.

Comment: PS you should stop writing code that manipulates C strings and uses C-style I/O (via `printf)` in favor of the typical C++ approaches, e.g. `std::string` and using `std::cout`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `const` qualifier to declarations of the variable and the function to fix this:

```
const char* decodeCode(const char* encodedString) {
    ....
    const char* a = encodedString;
    ....
}
```

---

Note: The bottom of your function is missing, but make sure that you are not returning `store` without copying it.

Comment: @user1590595 This compiled fine for me, here is a [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/0harb).

Comment: yes you are right , i was editing second copy of program instead of first, which i was compiling. now everything is working fine .thank you for kind help