# warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524356/c-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char)

I was looking into strings in C++ and tried an exercise to experiment the behaviour of some of the functions defined in the string library. I compiled the same program yesterday and everything worked with absolutely no warnings or errors. However, today I tried to compile the program again, but I received the following warning.

```
D:\C++ CodeBlocks Ex\Strings\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
D:\C++ CodeBlocks Ex\Strings\main.cpp|11|warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

the warning referes to this line `strncat("Hello",string,STRMAX-strlen(string));`. I am not sure but from what I suspect is that the strncat function does not like the ideaa of having to concatenate an array of literals with a string constant. Any help on this will be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    #define STRMAX 599
    char string[STRMAX+1];
    cout<<"Enter name: ";
    cin.getline(string,STRMAX);
    strncat("Hello",string,STRMAX-strlen(string));
    cout<<string;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the bigger issue here is that you're using `strncat()` entirely incorrectly.

Comment: Also you should use std::string instead of a char array.

Comment: You're using C strings, not C++ strings. C++'s string class and its methods live in the <string> header, not <string.h> (which is usually written as <cstring> in C++).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're supplying the arguments to `strncat()` in the wrong order. The first argument is the string to append to; the second argument is the string to append. As written, you're trying to add the input `string` to the constant string `"Hello"`, which isn't okay. You'll need to write this as two separate string operations.

Using the `std::string` class will save you a lot of grief.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will look into the std::string class. Appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using C++, I would recommend avoiding `char*` and using `std::string` instead.
If you need to pass in a `char*`, the string class has a `c_str()` method that returns the string in the form of a `const char*`.

Concatenation while using the string class is as easy as `"Hello " + "World!"`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int MaxLength = 599;

int main() {
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Enter a name: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    if (name.length() > MaxLength) {
        name = name.substr(0, MaxLength);
    }

    // These will do the same thing.
    // std::cout << "Hello " + name << endl;
    std::cout << "Hello " << name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't fully answer your question, but I guess it might help.

Answer (score 3):

A better way of writing this is with the string class and skip char completely.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string name;
    std::cout<<"Enter name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::string welcomeMessage = "Hello " + name;
    std::cout<< welcomeMessage;
    // or just use:
    //std::cout << "Hello " << name;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char * strncat(char * destination, const char * source, size_t num);
```

So your source and destination are the wrong way around.

Comment: Newbie error, thanks a lot, works now.