# Function incompatible with C++11 specification

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a problem here.
This function:

```
BOOL WINAPI SFileGetFileName(HANDLE hFile, char * szFileName) {
    TMPQFile * hf = (TMPQFile *)hFile;  // MPQ File handle
    char *szExt = "xxx";                // Default extension
    DWORD dwFirstBytes[2];              // The first 4 bytes of the file
    DWORD dwFilePos;                    // Saved file position

    int nError = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    int i;

    // Pre-zero the output buffer
    if(szFileName != NULL)
        *szFileName = 0;

    // Check valid parameters
    if(nError == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if(hf == NULL || szFileName == NULL)

            nError = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    }



    // If the file name is already filled, return it.

    if(nError == ERROR_SUCCESS && *hf->szFileName != 0)

    {

        if(szFileName != hf->szFileName)

            strcpy(szFileName, hf->szFileName);

        return TRUE;

    }



    if(nError == ERROR_SUCCESS)

    {

        if(hf->dwBlockIndex == (DWORD)-1)

            nError = ERROR_CAN_NOT_COMPLETE;

    }



    // Read the first 8 bytes from the file

    if(nError == ERROR_SUCCESS)

    {

        dwFirstBytes[0] = dwFirstBytes[1] = 0;

        dwFilePos = SFileSetFilePointer(hf, 0, NULL, FILE_CURRENT);   

        SFileReadFile(hFile, &dwFirstBytes, sizeof(dwFirstBytes), NULL);

        BSWAP_ARRAY32_UNSIGNED(dwFirstBytes, sizeof(dwFirstBytes) / sizeof(DWORD));

        SFileSetFilePointer(hf, dwFilePos, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    }



    if(nError == ERROR_SUCCESS)

    {

        if((dwFirstBytes[0] & 0x0000FFFF) == ID_EXE)

            szExt = "exe";

        else if(dwFirstBytes[0] == 0x00000006 && dwFirstBytes[1] == 0x00000001)

            szExt = "dc6";

        else

        {

            for(i = 0; id2ext[i].szExt != NULL; i++)

            {

                if(id2ext[i].dwID == dwFirstBytes[0])

                {

                    szExt = id2ext[i].szExt;

                    break;

                }

            }

        }



        // Create the file name

        sprintf(hf->szFileName, "File%08lu.%s", hf->dwBlockIndex, szExt);

        if(szFileName != hf->szFileName)

            strcpy(szFileName, hf->szFileName);

    }

    return (nError == ERROR_SUCCESS);

}
```

Gives me these errors on 'make':

```
SFileReadFile.cpp: In function ‘bool SFileGetFileName(HANDLE, char*)’:
SFileReadFile.cpp:655:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 char *szExt = "xxx";                // Default extension
               ^
SFileReadFile.cpp:700:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
         szExt = "exe";
               ^
SFileReadFile.cpp:702:19: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
         szExt = "dc6";
               ^
SFileReadFile.cpp:716:72: warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘DWORD {aka unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
     sprintf(hf->szFileName, "File%08lu.%s", hf->dwBlockIndex, szExt);
```

Please give me tips, how to fix these?

I have tried much in C++ documentation, but I had no much luck in finding what is needed. Look, I cannot do a `const char const*` in declaration of `szext` because I get many errors about constants. But I really want to get rid of these errors.

Please give me some advices or deeper explanation on why it's happening.

Comment: Does `char const *szExt = "xxx";` work? (Note the additional `const`). A string array `"xx"` is a `char const[]` and the conversion to `char*` was deprecated circa C++14. Using `char const*` should be preferred.

Comment: You're right that `szExt` should not be defined as `const char *const szExt`, but what suggestion did you find that made you think to try that? Knowing your understanding will allow for far more useful answers.

Comment: @Niall Yes, that's right, but unfortunately with most questions like these, merely giving the correct answer does nothing to help anyone actually understand what's going on. (Maybe it's different here.)

Comment: @hvd, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524356/c-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char look Howard Lovatt answer please. There was a const char const*

Comment: @Niall, yeah, this works! Can you explain why char const* actually worked? That'll help me to not repeat the question. This got rid of szExt related errors but it still throws me %lu format error.

Comment: @Duosora Yes, in that answer `temp` is only initialised and never re-assigned, so in that answer, the second `const` makes sense. In your code, you do re-assign `szExt`, so the second `const` does not make sense, but the first still does.

Comment: `char* szExt = "xxx";` allows you to overwrite your string literal `"xxx"` which may be stored in read-only memory causing a crash. In fact it doesn't make sense to be able to over-write a string literal so `const char* szExt = "xxx"; is correct.

Comment: @Duosora. It relates to the C++14 (possibly 11) deprecation of the conversion from `char const[]` to `char*` (IIRC was originally a compatibility issue with C). On the placement of the `const`, I've heard people say it's best read right to left, so `char const*` is a pointer to a constant character (array). If you wish it to be a `const` pointer, then `char const* const` which is a constant pointer to a constant character array.

Comment: I don't understand your indention & why you put so much empty lines.

Comment: @Niall That conversion was actually deprecated before C++11, and removed entirely in C++11.

Comment: @hvd. Thanks. I wasn't exactly sure on all the timelines and when it happened.

Answer (score 0):

These are not the errors you are getting the warning messages, and your program will work correctly.

In c++11 the initializing string the way you are using are depricated.

See other answers or you can use `std::string str="xxx";`

but you need to include  header

Comment: I'd like to get rid of these warnings because they're too annoying ;)

Answer (score 0):

String literals in C++ have type of **const character** arrays. So you have to use a pointer to a const char if you ar going to assign a string literal to a character pointer.

So it would be more correctly to write

```
const char *szExt = "xxx";
```

Or you could use a character array instead of the pointer if you do not want to use qualifier const

```
char szExt[] = "xxx";
```

Take into account that any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: const char* throws me another warning, but char const* doesn't. Seems strange.

Comment: @Duosora const char * and char const * are equivalent declaration sequences. The compiler can not issue a warning relative to these records.