# "Deprecated conversion from string constant to char*" when using BGI?

Tags: c, codeblocks, bgi

I recently installed code::blocks 13.12 and also added the BGI graphics (I know its too old; needed it for a project). But a simple C++ graphics program like this -

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int gd=DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

    circle(150,150,40);

    getch();
    closegraph();    
}
```

gives me a warning - "deprecated conversion from string constant to char* [-Wwrite-strings]"

Also the program does not execute; instead a pop-up window appears saying that "test.exe has stopped working"

I performed all the steps mentioned in videos online to add graphics in c::b
(Eg. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHmwwwPxpV8)

I noticed that my C: drive does not have a TC folder. Is that responsible? If yes, where do I get the required files?

One last thing - all programs that do not have graphics run smoothly.

Comment: Please check [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524356/c-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char) to see if fixing your deprecated conversion error fixes any more of the problems with the code.

Comment: Line no 7 where initgraph function is used warning is pointing that line is there any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

`char driver[]="C:\\TC\\BGI";`
solution for `"deprecated conversion from string constant to char* [-Wwrite-strings]"`.
use it as
`initgraph(&gd,&gm,driver);`