# Why am I not allowed to assign a result of function returning const char* to char*, bt a string literal(constant) can be assigned to char*?

Tags: c++, c

Function returning a `const char *` cannot be assigned to `char*`

```
const char* func() {
    return "This is a const string two ";
}
```

but `char*` is assigned a constant string in main directly:

```
int main() {
    char *d =" this is a const string one"; // works fine
    char *e = func();   // error cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char *'
    return 1;
}
```

Why the contradiction?

Comment: A string literal is special. In particular, it is not a `const char*`.

Comment: Is this C or C++? String literals are slightly different in the two different languages.

Comment: This is indeed an inconsistent behavior slightly remedied since c++11 in which case you will get a warning for the first assignment

Comment: Please delete either the C or the C++ tag. Answers will be different depending on language.

Comment: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to `char*`, so your "works fine" is situational at-best.

Comment: string literals are immutable since they reside in the read-only portion of the memory. If you use a string literal like you have shown they ought to be const char*.

Comment: **Neither is allowed**. Your compiler is just being forgiving in the *"works fine"* case.

Comment: The answer to "Why am I not allowed to assign a result of function returning const char* to char*?" is because `const`-qualification cannot be removed by implicit conversion.   But it seems your real question is "Why does the line with the string literal compile?" , or "why does string literal behave differently to `const char *`". Suggest editing title to clarify

Comment: Please suggest the answers for C as well as for C++ . @joachim Pileborg

Comment: Why does the line with the string literal compile? considering " this is a const string one" is read only ie const @M.M

Comment: @Malik the question linked by Lundin explains that

Comment: Lets say the above code is in C , then writing d[3]='k' results in runtime error . why ?

Comment: Do you mean there is a difference in memory layout difference @molbdnilo .
Can you explain the speciality of string literal .

Answer (score 7):

Assigning a string literal to `char*` is inherited from C, where this has been allowed since long before C had a `const` keyword.

In later C++ standards, [this has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524356/c-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char). A modern compiler ought to warn you about that.