# Loading graphic files

Tags: c, gcc, bgi

```
#include <graphics.h> //importing graphics
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int gd=0,gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm," ");
    circle(100,80,20);
    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

I typed the above code in Code::Blocks but it does not execute and rather it says

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
```

I have been trying for three days. Someone please help me out.
I have installed `winbgim.h` and other necessary files for graphics but it's not helping. I have searched all possible websites...

[image: The red color is indicating the error line]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char\*'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524356/c-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char)

Comment: Please decide which language you are using. C is not C++

Comment: The OP apparently having chosen C, the suggested dupe target seems inapplicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preamble: I deleted and then undeleted this answer several times.  There are other questions that address this subject, but most of them seem to be focused on C++, which has some differences from C in this area, or to have been closed as a dupe of such a question.  Some have answers I don't care for, or that are incomplete.  In a possiuble act of hubris, therefore, I am providing this answer, and I choose to provide it here.

---

Since the only string constant I see in the code is the `" "` argument to `initgraph()`, the warning must arise from there.  In that case, the third parameter to that function must be declared as type `char *`.

In that case, there is nothing inherently wrong with the code you presented.  According to the standard, string constants correspond to arrays of `char`, and such an array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element in most contexts where it is evaluated, including when it appears as a function argument.  That lines up perfectly with the function.

The problem is that the standard also says that if a program attempts to modify the contents of a string literal then it produces undefined behavior.  It is not uncommon for the actual manifestation of that to be a program crash.  Therefore, although it is technically legal, you take a significant risk when you convert a string constant to a `char *`, because whoever handles the pointer may not know that it is unsafe to attempt to use it to modify what it points to.  This problem does not arise if you convert to `const char *` instead.

GCC wants to help you detect such problems.  Therefore its `-Wwrite-strings]` option, when enabled, causes string constants to be treated as arrays of `const char` instead of arrays of `char`, and therefore to trigger warnings such as you encountered.

You have at least three options:

1. You could disable the `-Wwrite-strings` compilation option.  This is probably the best approach for legacy code with well-tested behavior, but I do not recommend it otherwise.
2. Provided that the function in fact does not attempt to modify the array that its parameter points to, directly or indirectly, you can change the function parameter to type `const char *`.  This may require a cascade of other, similar changes to avoid additional, relevant warnings.
3. Avoid passing a string literal to the function.  Instead create and pass a mutable array of `char`.  For example:

```
int gd = 0, gm;
char s[] = " ";

initgraph(&gd, &gm, s);
// ...
```

Note in particular that there, although there is a string literal, it is used only to *initialize* the distinct, non-`const` array `s`.

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnBollinger with that one above..... I did the same(I saved the file as .cpp then it worked) ....The program compiles but when I run the code, it stops working.... And in the build messages, it says **Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown)**....Why does this happen?

Comment: @RabinBK, your new problem sounds like an issue with your project configuration.  Possibly such a problem could arise from changing the source file suffix (which, I note, was not among my suggestions, and is not necessarily safe).  I cannot really say more about it.